# angular.js link function undefined

Tags: angularjs

I try to implement a Angular.js directive which will disable the button until the promise is returned. I found some examples. But when I try to call the function inside directive link. It always tell me the newClick() function is undefined. Can someone tell me why? Thanks a lot.

```
    angular.module('myApp.directives.newClick', [])
  .directive('newClick', [function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        newClick: '&'
      },
      link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.bind('click', function () {
          iElement.prop('disabled', true);
          scope.newClick().finally(function () {
            iElement.prop('disabled', false);
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: could you expose your newClick function and add view example? ideally would be creating fiddle.

Comment: Note that is should be `new-click="someFunc()"`, **not** `new-click="someFunc"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine as long as:

1. The `newClick` directive is properly set on the element.
2. It references a function that returns a promise.

---

E.g.:

```
<button new-click="clickFunc()">Click me</button>

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($q, $scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.clickFunc = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve('Hello, wolrd !');
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise;
    };        
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Zq7eT/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.. I found out what is my problem. I forget to return my $http promise in my function.......